# Python imports from sibling directories (Python 3)

Tags: python, import

Here are the relevant parts of my directory structure:

```
.
├── Pages
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── homepage.py
│   └── locators.py
└── TestCases
    ├── __init__.py
    └── sign_in.py
```

My sign_in.py looks like this:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from Pages.homepage import Homepage

# Test Sign In
class sign_in():
    def setup(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        
    def test_sign_in(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get('https://google.com')
        driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)
        h = Homepage(driver)
        h.signin().click()
        time.sleep(50)
```

My `homepage.py` looks like this:

```
from locators import Locator
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class Homepage(object):
    def __init__(self,driver):
        self.driver = driver
    
        self.signin = driver.find.element(By.XPATH, Locator.sign_in)
```

Whenever I run `sign_in.py`, I get an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pages'
```

I'm not sure what's happening because IntelliSense doesn't see anything wrong with it.

I've tried using this in my `sign_in.py` file:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
from Pages.homepage import Homepage
```

But haven't had any luck.

I'm still planning this environment out, so moving things around isn't a big deal, and I'd rather restructure things than rely on hacky workarounds.

Comment: How do you execute the code?

Comment: Can you try doing `from ..Pages ...`

Comment: @mkrieger1 I'm in VSCode and I'm just clicking the Run button. Running `python .\TestCases\sign_in.py` gives the same result.


@airblast That gives me `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package `

Comment: When you run `python .\TestCases\sign_in.py` I think you should get an error "no module named 'locators'" from homepage.py instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Import the Systems library
`import sys`

Import the Operating System Library
`import os`

save your files directory
`currentDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`

store the Pages Directory in a variable
`pathToPages = os.path.join(currentDir, '..', 'Pages')`

append the path to your environment
`sys.path.append(pathToPages)`

Now you're able to import the file within the next line:
`from homepage import Homepage`

Hope this helps!